# Problema na Importação de modulo Python

Tags: python

Estou com um proble, uso Python 3.6.7 estou fazendo uma aplicação Flask com a seguinte estrutura:

```
   /app
    /arquivospy
        consultaMercados.py
        definirMercados.py
        interfaceBD.py
        main.py

        outros arquivos py

    /static
    /templates    
    app.py
    form.py
```

dentro da pasta /arquivospy tem uns scripts py que uso para ler um TXT e cadastrar no BD gerar umas medias fazer unas contas e salvar no BD tem scripts de consulta ao BD, tem o arquivo main.py que uso no shell mesmo, ele tem um menuzinho que eu informo o nome do arquivo TXT e ele automatiza tudo, ou seja dentro da pasta /arquivospy ta tudo funcionando certo.

O problema é com app.py que faz as rotas Flask, ele importa:

import arquivospy.interfaceBD  e da esse erro:

```
File "app.py", line 7, in 
    import arquivospy.interfaceBD
  File "/home/karont/SiteHtml/app/arquivospy/interfaceBD.py", line 2, in 
    import definirMercados as mercados
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'definirMercados'
```

Comment: No arquivo `interfaceBD` coloque `import . definirMercados` com o ponto para deixar o caminho de importação relativo.

Comment: se fizer isso da erro invalid syntax

Comment: Sim, por um momento li que estava usando o `from .definirMercados import ...`, só com o `import` não funciona mesmo. Então coloque o caminho completo de importação: `import arquivospy.definirMercados as mercados`

Comment: Se eu fizer isso o app.py funciona a plicação roda faço tudo certo no Browser, mas se precisar usar o main.py para cadastrar novas coisas, ai da erro tenho que retirar todos os import arquivospy. em todos os arquivos py que alterei  e colocar  import definirMercados as mercados, ou seja tem que voltar a funcionar olhando para mesma pasta

Comment: Você criou o arquivo `__init__.py` nas pastas onde está cada módulo?

Comment: Já criei vazio ja criei com __ALL__ = [nome do arquivos.py] e nada vi falado que a partir do python 3.4 não era mas preciso. o problema ta no app.py chamar um modulo(interfaceBD.py) e esse modulo fazer seu trabalho interagindo com os modulos irmão dele (dentro da mesma pasta)

Comment: Ih, não vi os comentários, :D Você está executando sua aplicação a partir de onde, a partir de qual arquivo em qual diretório?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, bom dia! Tudo bem?

```
# O seu módulo interfaceBD está importando definirMercados
File "/home/karont/SiteHtml/app/arquivospy/interfaceBD.py", line 2, in
import definirMercados as mercados
# Aqui ele diz que não conseguiu encontrar o módulo definirMercados que foi importado
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'definirMercados'
```

Tente importar o módulo *definirMercados* dentro do arquivo *interfaceBD.py* da mesma forma que você fez dentro do *app.py*, ou seja, tente trocar a sua linha de importação para:

```
import arquivospy.definirMercados as mercados
```

**[EDITADO]**
Quando você insere um import no módulo, essa importação é relativa ao diretório raiz a partir do qual você está executando a sua aplicação.
Se você entra no diretório *arquivospy* com o shell e tenta executar o *main.py* a partir dele, então todas as importações presentes no *main.py* tentam buscar os módulos a partir desse diretório, por isso o
*import arquivospy.definirMercados*
não funciona dentro do diretório onde está o *main.py*.

Duas soluções possíveis são:

1. Mover o arquivo *main.py* para o mesmo diretório onde está o *app.py* para poder executá-lo deste local;
2. Executar o *main.py* no terminal a partir do diretório onde está o *app.py*;

Comment: dentro da pasta /app eu rodo app.py que é o que me da a interface Web(Flask) e os arquivos dentro de /app/arquivospy é que fazem todo o trabalho da aplicação do jeito que ta dentro da pasta /app/arquivospy eles tão trabalhando perfeito sem erro o problema ta em o app.py chamar esses modulos dentro da pasta /app/arquivospy e eles continuarem trabalhando,

Comment: para eles trabalharem tenho que ir em todos os arquivo.py dentro da pasta /app/arquivospy e mudar o import para : arquivospy.nomedoarquivo.py ai o app.py roda e faz tudo certo, mas ai o modulo que rodo direto no shell main.py para de funcionar; ai tenho que voltar todos os aquivos.py que foram alterados para o import direto(na mesma pasta) import nomedoaquivo.py; esse main.py eu executo ele manualmente de vez em quando só quando quero alimentar o BD

Comment: Como você está fazendo para executar o main.py?  
Você está entrando dentro do diretório 'arquivospy' com o shell e executando-o a partir daí?  
Os imports no Python são relativos ao diretório do qual se está executando o módulo, se for isso, tente mover o main.py para o mesmo diretório onde está o app.py para ver se funciona.  
Ou tente executar o main a partir do diretório app/ (o mesmo diretório onde está o app.py).

Comment: isso mesmo  movi o main.py para o diretório /app e funcionou, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! Editei a resposta ;)